# Access the corect methods from multiple base classes based on some template parameter and without shadowing them

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following sketch

```
//g++  7.4.0

#include <iostream>

template<int T>
struct X {
    static int type() { return T; };    
};

template<typename T>
struct FooBase {
    int foo() { return T::type(); }
};

struct Foo : public FooBase<X<1>>, public FooBase<X<2>> {
    
    template<int T>
    int foo() { return FooBase<X<T>>::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    
    Foo fobj;
    
    std::cout << fobj.foo<1>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << fobj.foo<2>() << std::endl;
}
```

This example works, whenever I call `fobj.foo<1>()` or `fobj.foo<2>()` the correct foo method from its corresponding base class is called.

My question is if there is a way to get rid of this 'wrapper' method

```
template<int T>
int foo() { return FooBase<X<T>>::foo(); }
```

method from the Foo class and access the correct method from the base classes some other way. I am asking this because let's assume that `FooBase` class has already a lot of methods and I don't like that in class `Foo` I need to create that wrapper just to call the correct method from the base class.

Comment: How should the compiler know which is the "correct" method you wanna call, if you don't specify it somehow? Or in other words, how should the call site look like, ideally?

Comment: @florestan I know that the compiler can't know which one to call if you don't specify it somehow, what i was wondering was if there is a nicer, or a more generic solution to this which doesn't involve duplicating the methods (or shadowing them). Maybe there are some tricks using templates somehow? That's what i am asking

Comment: The solution you have right now seems to convey the intent. Can you show what you would ideally like to write? (Even if it doesn't compile)

Comment: @cigien ideally i would like to call the methods like in the example I posted `fobj.foo<1>()` but without having to define the foo method again in the `Foo` class. This would be of course the ideal way which probably is not possible with all the tricks in the world, but I am fine with another call signature if i can get rid of the duplicated foo method in `Foo` class

Comment: @cigien The best way would be to overload the non existent operator `<>` haha and do it like this `fobj<1>.foo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's one way you could do it. As your `Foo` derives from the bases, you could add the disambiguation one step ahead by adding the following function to `Foo`:

```
template<int I>
FooBase<X<I>>& as_base() { return static_cast<FooBase<X<I>>&>(*this); }
```

The call site would look like

```
Foo f;
f.as_base<1>().foo();
```

Still not really beautiful, but at least you'd not have to write delegates for all functions.

See complete example [here.](https://godbolt.org/z/oafmVo)

Comment: This is definitely one way to do it, I had this in mind as well. I will wait a little bit more, maybe some other ideas come up, I think this is the best way to do it so far